# writing arrays values into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have retrieved the direct messages from my twitter account and i want to store senderid, sender screen name and text in mysql database tables, in order to be read by the Artificial intellingece markup language engine so it can reply accordingly. After i execute the program, i checked the database and no row has been entered from the array and no error message either.

Here's my code:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

// Get direct message data 
$content = $connection ->get('https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json');

echo '<pre>',print_r($content,true),'</pre>';

function write_messages_to_database() {

require_once('connect_to_database');

$conn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "Diego", "frafra") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('bot', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

foreach ($content as $directmessage) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'twitter_senders' ('sender_id', 'sender_name'), VALUES ('{$content->id}', '{$content->sender_screen_name}')");
   $directmessage_id = mysql_last_insert_id();
   foreach ($directmessage->text as $text) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'message_senders' ('message'), VALUES ('{$text->text}')");
   } 

 }
}
```

Below, the array from which i just want to extract the values in `id`,`sender_screen_name` 
and `text`. Also, the array has three objects but i just pasted in one for the example.

What do you think?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sender_id] => 374504554
            [recipient_screen_name] => Infobot2012
            [recipient_id] => 428575951
            [recipient] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 428575951
                    [profile_image_url] => 
                    [url] => 
                    [created_at] => Sun Dec 04 22:56:38 +0000 2011
                    [followers_count] => 3
                    [default_profile] => 1
                    [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                    [lang] => en
                    [utc_offset] => 
                    [name] => Diego Canale
                    [profile_background_image_url] => 
                    [location] => 
                    [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                    [listed_count] => 0
                    [verified] => 
                    [protected] => 
                    [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                    [is_translator] => 
                    [following] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [profile_text_color] => 333333
                    [statuses_count] => 10
                    [screen_name] => Infobot2012
                    [profile_image_url_https] => 
                    [time_zone] => 
                    [profile_background_image_url_https] => 
                    [friends_count] => 14
                    [default_profile_image] => 1
                    [contributors_enabled] => 
                    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                    [id_str] => 428575951
                    [geo_enabled] => 
                    [favourites_count] => 0
                    [profile_background_tile] => 
                    [notifications] => 
                    [show_all_inline_media] => 
                    [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                    [follow_request_sent] => 
                )

            [id_str] => 194550124767227905
            [sender] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 374504554
                    [profile_image_url] => 
                    [url] => 
                    [created_at] => Fri Sep 16 12:46:20 +0000 2011
                    [followers_count] => 19
                    [default_profile] => 1
                    [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                    [lang] => en
                    [utc_offset] => 
                    [name] => Diego Canale
                    [profile_background_image_url] => 
                    [location] => Dublin
                    [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                    [listed_count] => 0
                    [verified] => 
                    [protected] => 
                    [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                    [is_translator] => 
                    [following] => 1
                    [description] => 
                    [profile_text_color] => 333333
                    [statuses_count] => 92
                    [screen_name] => sdiegolo
                    [profile_image_url_https] => 
                    [time_zone] => 
                    [profile_background_image_url_https] => 
                    [friends_count] => 79
                    [default_profile_image] => 
                    [contributors_enabled] => 
                    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                    [id_str] => 374504554
                    [geo_enabled] => 
                    [favourites_count] => 1
                    [profile_background_tile] => 
                    [notifications] => 
                    [show_all_inline_media] => 
                    [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                    [follow_request_sent] => 
                )

            [created_at] => Mon Apr 23 22:15:38 +0000 2012
            [id] => 1.9455012476723E+17
            [sender_screen_name] => sdiegolo
            [text] => Hello Infobot!
        )
```

Comment: **warning your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! (please someone correct this code!)

Comment: As @DanielA.White says, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You really should use prepared statements.  If you don't understand what they are, or why you need them, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I don't think twitter will do a SQL Injection attack, in this case.

Comment: @GabrielSantos: "`INSERT INTO 'message_senders' ('message'), VALUES ('{$text->text}')`" - who knows what text such a direct message might contain.

Comment: Sorry, heave read only `"INSERT INTO 'twitter_senders' (...`.

Comment: where you defined `$content` inside `write_messages_to_database()`? And when you call the function?

Comment: I also really hope you haven't just posted your genuine MySQL login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you ever calling your `write_messages_to_database()` function?
2. In any event, I recommend you redefine it along the following lines:

   ```
   function write_messages_to_database($content) {
       // Use PDO - it'll make your life so much easier
       $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=bot;host=127.0.0.1', "Diego", "frafra");

       // use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection
       // see http://bobby-tables.com for more info
       // great thing is, we can prepare once and use many!
       $sender_stmt = $dbh->prepare("
           INSERT INTO twitter_senders (sender_id, sender_name)
           VALUES (:id, :name)
       ");
       $sender_stmt->bindParam(":id"  , $sender_id  );
       $sender_stmt->bindParam(":name", $sender_name);

       $message_stmt = $dbh->prepare("
           INSERT INTO message_senders (message) VALUES (:text)
       ");
       $message_stmt->bindParam(":text", $text);

       foreach ($content as $directmessage) {
          $sender_id   = $directmessage->sender->id  ;
          $sender_name = $directmessage->sender->name;
          $sender_stmt->execute();

          // this is pointless...
          $directmessage_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

          $text = $directmessage->text;
          $message_stmt->execute();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i put all the functions on a separate php file, as in the code section of this message. The problem is that when trying the above script,the object 'text'is not going into the database as it seems separate inside the array, as in below:

    )
            [created_at] => Mon Apr 23 22:15:38 +0000 2012
            [id] => 1.9455012476723E+17
            [sender_screen_name] => sdiegolo
            [text] => Hello Infobot!

[code]

require_once('functions.php');

connect_to_database();

write_messages_to_database($content);

[/code]

Comment: @DiegoCanale: I think, as the comments in my answer suggested, that the `text` part is not an array - therefore `foreach($directmessage->text as $text)` never gets entered; replace it instead with a simple `$text = $directmessage->text`, as shown in the updated answer above.

Comment: i am getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" in reference to the line $message_stmt->execute();

Comment: Please check your code is exactly as above.  If you can't find any differences, please update your question with your current code and we can take a look.

Comment: $sender_stmt = $dbh->prepare("
        INSERT INTO twitter_senders (sender_id)
        VALUES (:id)
    ");
    $sender_stmt->bindParam(":id"  , $sender_id  );
 
 $message_stmt = $dbh->prepare("
 INSERT INTO twitter_senders (sender_alias) VALUES (:sender_screen_name),
 INSERT INTO message_senders (sender_id, message) VALUES (:id, :text)
 
 ");

    foreach ($content as $directmessage) {
       $sender_id   = $directmessage->sender->id  ;
       $sender_stmt->execute();
 
 $alias = $directmessage-> sender_screen_name
 $text = $directmessage->text   
 $message_stmt->execute();
   
    }
 
 
  }

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in reference to line of code $text = $directmessage->text.

Comment: Well, that's not the code shown in my answer.  Please try using the code as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you unless we know what the error is.

Try doing this:

```
foreach ($directmessage->text as $text) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'message_senders' ('message'), VALUES ('{$text->text}')") 
        or die(mysql_error());
       }
```

Further, a better way to do this would be:

```
foreach ($directmessage->text as $text) {
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO 'message_senders' ('message'), VALUES ('%s')"
                , mysql_real_escape_string($text->text));
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: i don't get any error message, it's just the program is not writing into the database